# Krakow MDA Bus stop - tickets to Busko Zdroj

Tags: tickets, buses, krakow

I must take a bus of the MAT- BUS
Company from Krakow to Busko Zdroj on Nov 25, around 4 pm o'clock.

1. I don't know were the bus is located (on first floor, but if possible some more info, like platform number/letter
2. Is it possible to buy a ticket with the driver?
3. If I buy a ticket should it be specific to a certain bus hour departure, or if I miss that hour, can I use the ticket for the next bus?

Answer (score 1):

1. It should be printed on a display. They are usually hard to see yet present. One is above the ticket point.
2. Should be. In fact, they stop selling tickets in the station building ten minutes before the departure.

Comment: Thanks, I hope I'll manage, though I have a previous experiece with MDA, a bad one, a abit of a chaos.